# Is there any way to compound two different Python files to be extracted in one Docx document?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two different Python files. Each of them scraps some data from websites, and they print the data into a docx file. However, I want to compound them and print the all data to one single docx file. For example:

Headline from file1
Data from file1
Data from file1

Headline from file2
Data from file2
Data from file2

They should be in the same document, but I really couldn't figure it out.. I'm a total beginner, so can you show me how to do that? I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Here are the codes:

code1:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://www.brookings.edu/events/"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

heading = document.add_heading().add_run("Brookings Institute")
heading.font.name = "Cambria"
heading.font.size = Pt(14)


events = soup.find_all("article", class_ = "archive-view archive-event event-standard-view past")
for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("h4", class_ = "title")
    link = event.find("a", class_ = "event-content")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
        print(link['href'])
        document.add_paragraph(link['href'])
    except:
        continue

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Code2:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests
url = 'https://www.newamerica.org/api/event/?time_period=past&page_size=12&page=1&story_image_rendition=small'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

document = Document()

heading = document.add_heading().add_run("New America")
heading.font.name = "Cambria"
heading.font.size = Pt(14)

for i in data['results']:
    title = i['title']
    link = i['url']
    try:
        print(f'Title: {title}\nURL: {link}\n\n')
        document.add_paragraph({title}, style='List Bullet')
        document.add_paragraph({link}, style='List Bullet')
    except:
        continue

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Comment: it will be simpler to put all code in one file.

Comment: if you want it in to files then better keep code in functions - and then you can `import` functions from file and execute them when you needed. But you should split code into functions like `read data from server`, `get data from HTML`, `create Document and save in file` - because some code is duplicated in both file and you will have to use only one of them.

Comment: `print()`  and `document.add_paragraph()` rather can't generate error so putting it in `try/except` is useless. You should rather use `try/except` for `i['title']` and `i['url']` because it may raise error if there is no `title` or `url` in `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, it could be simpler to put all code in one file and modify it.

If you have to use it in two files then you should reorganize it to keep code in functions

`script.py`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def get_items():

    items = []
    
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
    url = "https://www.brookings.edu/events/"
    data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

    events = soup.find_all("article", class_ = "archive-view archive-event event-standard-view past")

    for event in events:
        try:
            name = event.find("h4", class_="title").text
            link = event.find("a", class_="event-content")['href']
            
            items.append( [name, link] )
            
            print('name:', name)
            print('link:', link)
            print('---')
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', Exception)

    return items

def add_items(document, items):
    heading = document.add_heading().add_run("Brookings Institute")
    heading.font.name = "Cambria"
    heading.font.size = Pt(14)
    
    for text, link in items:
        document.add_paragraph(text, style='List Bullet')
        document.add_paragraph(link)
    
def main():

    document = Document()

    items = get_items()
    
    add_items(document, items)

    document.save('demo.docx')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`script2.py`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def get_items():

    items = []
    
    url = 'https://www.newamerica.org/api/event/?time_period=past&page_size=12&page=1&story_image_rendition=small'

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    for item in data['results']:
        try:
            title = item['title']
            link = item['url']
            
            items.append( [title, link] )

            print('title:', title)
            print('link:', link)
            print('---')
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)

    return items

def add_items(document, items):

    heading = document.add_heading().add_run("New America")
    heading.font.name = "Cambria"
    heading.font.size = Pt(14)

    for text, link in items:
        document.add_paragraph(text, style='List Bullet')
        document.add_paragraph(link, style='List Bullet')

def main():

    document = Document()
    
    items = get_items()
    
    add_items(document, items)

    document.save('demo.docx')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And you still can run every script as separated program.

But you can also import it to other file to run only selected functions and write all in one file

```
from docx import Document

import script1
import script2

def main():

    document = Document()
    
    items = script1.get_items()
    script1.add_items(document, items)

    items = script2.get_items()
    script2.add_items(document, items)

    document.save('demo.docx')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Because in both scripts I use the same functions so I can later use `for`-loop

```
from docx import Document

import script1
import script2

def main():

    document = Document()
    
    for s in [script1, script2]:
        items = s.get_items()
        s.add_items(document, items)

    document.save('demo.docx')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: it couldn't be more perfect. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Refactor:

Pseudo code:

```
Imports

Create document

Get info from site 1
Put info from site 1 in document

Get info from site 2
Put info from site 2 in document

Write document
```